# MySQL - Full vs partial row retrieval

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm programming a website using PHP/MySql to allow visitors to search for real estate listings.

The main page shows the list of advertised apartments, displaying just a small subset of all the available attributes included in the MySql table that contains the apartments listed.  The full set of attributes for each apartment is only shown on a secondary webpage, once the user selects a result from the list in the main page. So, if for example, the available features included in the database's table are price, location, number of rooms and surface area, the main page only displays price and location in the results list, and the remaining attributes are displayed only when the user selects a specific result from the list.

I'm wondering what is the best strategy in order to ensure fast response from the database and achieve the highest possible amount of concurrent users: Should I retrieve ALL the columns from the table when showing the full result list of results and avoid querying the database when the user selects a given result (since I already have all the data I need to show), or should I only extract the minimum amount of columns to display in the results list (price and location, following the example above), and fetch the remaining columns for a specific record only when the user selects a specific result?

I'm querying a single table (no joins or complex queries, although I do use a where clause) and the results list is expected to show around 30 to 50 records at a time. I don't have any data regarding how many of the results in the list shown are selected by the user to see additional info, but I would say it's resonable to say that it will select around 60% of them.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd fetch the first few rows and then use endless scrolling techniques via ajax. Be sure to have a (sometimes a little outdated) static list of all entries (meaning: cache them) linked to from every page. That way Google can reference every "sigle view object pages".

Comment: When it comes to scalability it all depends on how you want to grow that business. Until it becomes a big thing you might be good to keep it simple. Just start off by implementing the easiest way. When customer numbers start to grow it's soon enough to think bigger. That's the "lean" way to think about scale. On the other hand you could "make up" a number of visitors you expect and then implement a simple solution and use stress test software to simulate that number of simultaneous requests.